# Multilanguage and select option

Tags: php, html

I'm working with a multi-language site, and there is an HTML `select` element with 100 choices. The code looks like this:

```
<option value="1"><? echo $lang['CARGOTYPE_1']; ?></option>
```

So system insert into mysql table "type" number "1", or number "2" pr...

But when I select number from mysql, I need to change number to word.

With if, else I can change its meanings:

```
If($type == 1) { echo $lang['CARGOTYPE_1']; } elseif($type == 2){ echo $lang...
```

But the problem is, that code will be very long...

Any smart solutions for my problem?

Comment: I am not sure what you want... If you want to "echo" something with arguments, you can do something like `echo $lang['CARGOTYPE_'.$type];`. But, is that you need ?

Comment: first explain breifly what do you want?

Comment: MTranchant thats right what I needed! Very simple solution. Thanks.

Comment: Added as response. Did not understand why you choose panther solution, but, never mind....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know number of choices, use for cycle for that.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++) {
    echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $lang['CARGOTYPE_' . $i] . '</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want... If you want to "echo" something with arguments, you can do something like :

```
echo $lang['CARGOTYPE_'.$type];
```

But, is that you need ?